# Catch EndpointNotFoundException in Biztalk 2010 Orchestration

Tags: exception, biztalk, orchestration

I would like to handle an EndpointNotFoundException in my orchestration.

I add a new exception handler

scope synchronized = false

exception object type = System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException (this object type doesn't work)

exception object type = System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException (this object type doesn't work)

exception object type = System.SystemException (this object type worked. which i don't want)

Any idea on how to catch such exceptions in orchestration ?

Comment: How do you know the catch block is not working?

Comment: I'm writing custom error messages in event viewer within each catch block using expression shape.

Comment: So how do you know what type of exception is being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a common issue - e.g. [here](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_2009/f/32/p/13555/26455.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/biztalkgeneral/thread/4fcc83fc-1c53-400e-b2c0-df7fc1ec3923). I concur with you if I catch a basic `System.Exception` that the type being caught is `System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException` with an inner `System.Net.WebException`.

Although not directly answering your question, why not mark the port as `Delivery Notification = Transmitted`, and then catch the [DeliveryFailureException](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13576/A-developers-guide-to-handling-exceptions-in-BizTa)?.

This way, you decouple your orchestration from the specific adapter (WCF), and if you change your transport (or add a backup transport etc), the exception handling will still work.

Edit : Scott Colestock mentions a [hack to catch internal exceptions](http://www.traceofthought.net/2008/05/05/RAISERRORAndTheBizTalkSqlAdapter.aspx) - something similar might work for the original requirement

Comment: Delivery Notification won't work on a Request-Response port unfortunately.